# jupyter labextensions install w/o npm

Tags: jupyter-lab

The jupyeter lab documentation (http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html) asks to run the following command to install labextensions:

```
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
```

I am working behind a corporate firewall and getting node package manager to work properly is very difficult. Is there some other way to predownload labextensions and then do a local install without the need to use an internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently exploring if this is possible (as I have a similar server wherein I do not have admin privileges), but in the meantime, perhaps try using NVM (https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to install Node and NPM. This will at least help you get around needing to have root permissions (i.e. `sudo`).